# Why did Gretel try to light a fire?

Tags: plot-explanation, gretel-and-hansel

In the movie, Gretel & Hansel, when Hansel climbed into the window and started eating the food, a witch showed up and seemingly captured him.

Hansel first tried to break the window by throwing a stone at it, it did not work then Gretel started making a fire with dry leaves.

Why did she do that?